# How to get specific columns from related models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this code in my controller

```
$group = MatchOfficial::with([
            "role",
            "match",
            "match.facility",
            "match.facility.localName",
            "match.facility.location",
            "person",
            "person.users",
            "person.localName",
            "person.location",
        ])->when($person, function ($query) use ($person) {
                $query->where("person_id", $person);
            })
        ->get()->groupBy("person_id")
```

I want to retrieve specific columns from those relations, for example i want to get only 'name' column from person.localName relation, how can i do it ? I am using Laravel 8.12.

I tried to do something like this
person.localName:name, doesnt seem to be working. Also googled it, nada.

Answer (score -1):

i tested this with `:name` even in laravel 7 and that was true, are you sure about your column?

you have other option . give that with `select` like this:

```
group = MatchOfficial::with([
            "role",
            "match",
            "match.facility",
            "match.facility.localName",
            "match.facility.location",
            "person",
            "person.users",
            "person.localName",
            "person.location" => function ($q) {
                $q->select('name');
            },
        ])->when($person, function ($query) use ($person) {
                $query->where("person_id", $person);
            })
        ->get()->groupBy("person_id")
```

Comment: Nah, tried this also, its not working either (( I am assuming select() works only for Model itself, not for related model's columns

Comment: are you sure about your columns and names? because i tried with `:name` and `select` and their worked for me.

Comment: I am pretty sure. When i am trying with :name, my localName relation is returning null, no idea why. I dont get any errors tho.  Have you tried select with related model columns ? Its just not working, works only with the MatchOfficial model's columns